# How to retrieve MTLLanguageVersion in Metal

Tags: ios, metal

There is an `MTLLanguageVersion` enum documented at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtllanguageversion?language=objc which, if I understand correctly, returns current Metal shading language version at runtime.

The problem is, I can't figure out where to retrieve it. I can't find any related property on MTLDevice or some global function for this, and documentation doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MTLLanguageVersion** enum is used for configuring one of the compiler options, namely, [languageVersion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcompileoptions/1515494-languageversion?language=objc).

> You can configure the Metal compiler’s options by setting any or all
> of an [MTLCompileOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcompileoptions?language=objc) instance’s properties, including the
> following:
>
> - Target previous OS releases by assigning the [languageVersion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcompileoptions/1515494-languageversion?language=objc) property to an [MTLLanguageVersion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtllanguageversion?language=objc) case.
>
> You can compile a library with your compile options instance by
> calling a `MTLDevice` instance’s `newLibraryWithSource:options:error:`
> or `newLibraryWithSource:options:completionHandler:` method.